# Как объяснить ребёнку, в чем разница между «сказать то, что» и «сказать о том, что»? И когда какое выражение употреблять в речи?

Tags: выбор-слов, предлоги

Пример: я хотел сказать тебе, что я скучаю. Или: я хотел сказать тебе о том, что я скучаю.

Answer (score 1):

Скажи то, что видишь - что-то конкретное, назови, что видишь. Я вижу кошку, "кошка", "это кошка".

Скажи о том, что видишь - лучше, *расскажи о том, что видишь,* о кошке, о том, что видишь кошку. Я вижу кошку, я вижу кошку потому что кошка вылизывает себя, кошка мяучит.

То - про называние, конкретизацию вещи или понятия, терминологию.

О том - не о названии, а о процессе связанном с чем-то.

То - это что это такое? как это называется? что это значит?

Скажи то, что - назови.

Скажи/расскажи о том - что ты об этом думаешь?

То+м - м-мычание, молчание, мысли, процесс внутренней речи.

Э+то - э-процесс подбора слов, значений, названий, не мышление, а скорее торможение процесса вербализации).

Comment: Это не для ребёнка :) Не каждый взрослый поймёт ваш ответ. Станьте проще.

Comment: @oleedd я добавил, чтобы стало непонятнее)

Comment: Уже лучше......

Comment: @oleedd - а так?)

Comment: Ну, это хрен поймёшь :)

Comment: @oleedd ну есть слово то. К нему присоединяются необходимые элементы, частицы. Э - это когда экают, дефекты речи, когда говорят ЭЭЭ между фразами растягивая и компенсируя паузы для подбора нужных слов. А Мычат -ММ, скорее когда пытаются в целом сообразить, что говорят. Я просто вдруг подумал, может в этом есть такой смысл). Можно ответить ММ когда тебе что-то говорят, что будет означать "да", "я понял", "я подумаю", а если человек скажет Э-ээ - то это будет значит, что он не понял что это было, требует продолжить объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

Изъяснительное придаточное, которое относится к глаголу в главном, может соединяться как с помощью союза ‟о том, что”, так и с помощью союза ‟что”, взгляните на примеры:

> Он рассказал о том, что они прибудут = Он рассказал, что они прибудут.
> Она думала о том, что не выключила утюг = Она думала, что не выключила утюг.

Но если изъяснительное придаточное относится к существительному или местоимению, то оно присоединяется только с помощью союза ‟о том, что”:

> Он услышал рассказ о том, что они прибудут. (Хотя вас поймут, если вы используете ‟что”, но это всё же легкая грамматическая ошибка — люди так не говорят — и это режет слух носителю.)
> Её терзали мысли о том, что она не выключила утюг. (Хотя вас поймут, если вы используете ‟что”, но это всё же легкая грамматическая ошибка — люди так не говорят — и это режет слух носителю.)

Да, как объяснить разницу между ‟сказать, что” и ‟сказать о том, что”? С глаголами допустимо употреблять и то и другое. Семантической разницы нет: это как разница между ‟куплю хлеба” и ‟куплю такую еду, как хлеб”.

Comment: Я спрашиваю именно о разнице. Мне режет слуз, но я не могу объяснить, почему. Какая-то разница есть. Даже по смыслу. Я говорю, что ты не прав. Это я констатирую факт. Я говорю о том, что ты не прав. Это подразумевает какое-то долгое и развёрнутое повествование

Comment: "Такую еду, как хлеб" — ну и кто так говорит?

Comment: Я не писал, что так кто-то говорит, я писал, что смысл один и тот же — куплю такой предмет, как молоток = куплю молоток; срублю такое дерево, как липа = срублю липу и т.д.

Comment: @Евгения Исмаилова Нет, разницы никакой нет. Это просто какие-то ваши аморфные субъективные представления.

Comment: Есть, Jim Korbett, есть, и как раз та, что автор вопроса описывает. Зависит от контекста. Порой смысл тот же.

Comment: Сравните: *Говорю вот это. Рассказываю о вот этом.*